# Angular application wont show assets after being deployed to webspace

Tags: angular, deployment, frontend

When I deploy my angular app to an webspace no assets will get loaded.

`<img src="/assets/images/portfolio.png" alt="portfolio">`

This is how I implemented my images in my application.
[This is the error I'm facing in the dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKYs.png)

I tried adding a web.config and also changing the path of the image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, you probably should check where exactly is this image in your hosting, in which directory, and is this directory accessible, and alter your code accordingly, maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path to the image is correct?
Sometimes the best idea is to let the IDE "write the path himself" by writing "../" and following the suggestions.

[image]

Are you working on local host?